# Unable to access dll file on deployed c# mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dllimport

I have a c# mvc application which uses a c++ dll for some of the heavier statistical computation.  Everything works fine when I run it locally but on my deployed application all I get is

**Exception:** Unable to load DLL 'HandCalculatorDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The c# model is using

```
    [DllImport("HandCalculatorDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool CalculateWinner(int[] req);
    public RoundResult CalculateWinnerDll(List<Hand> hands, List<Card> board)
    {
        // set up the request
        // calls the dll
        var success = CalculateWinner(reqArr);
        // interpret the response
        return result;
    }
```

I've tried several different things but nothing seems to work for a **deployed** project.  I tried both adding the dll to the project and removing it from the project (based on different recommendations).  I tried several variations of relative and absolute paths.  I used

```
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/bin");
```

to find the abolute path on the hosting pc, placed the dll in that bin folder, and used that path as the DllImport attribute.

Unfortunately, most of the recommendations/solutions I've found only work for local debugging.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

**UPDATE**
I copied the entire project onto a second computer to run it and that computer is throwing the same "Unable to load DLL" error that occurs when I publish.  I'm running everything the exact same way on the second computer as on my home computer and I verified that the file is there.  Now I'm really confused...

Comment: Just making sure: have you included that DLL in your VS project? And if so, have you set its properties so that it's copied to the output directory on build?

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways.  No dice...

Comment: Once published, is your dll in the bin folder or not ? And is your dll 32bit? Try setting your web project to x86 or setting the app pool to 32bit in IIS.

Comment: I am compiling the project using 32bit.  When I first published the project to the host it would not run.  Once I clicked "Enable 32bit support" on my host's control panel the site became accessible.  There aren't any IIS specific controls though.

Comment: As far as the dll being in the bin folder, I've tried running it from multiple locations, including the bin.

Comment: On your second computer where it is giving you the same error try running `regsvr32 HandCalculatorDll.dll` in a command prompt window and see if that makes it work? If that works, it looks like you need the DLL registered in the gac.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the reference in your project,  click on properties and making sure it is set to copy local.

Comment: I currently have the Copy to Output Directory set to Copy if newer but I'm not sure if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: Sounds right.  Another thing is to make sure the folder your dll is in is in your project.  Cause when you publish it will only copy the folders in the project to the server

Comment: I've tried several variations, including running the dll from the main project folder.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you deploying? Are you using Web deploy, or do you have some other means of publishing?

Comment: My host does not support web deploy so I'm using FTP deploy.

Comment: It might be that to use DllImport you need your dll registered in your host's gac. Alternatively it will probably try and find it in your bin directory. Seeing as you bin directory only gets constructed during publishing your website it won't be there. So what I'd do is publish to a local path on your machine, go look at where your dll is relative to your bin directory and then in your ImportDll attribute update the path accordingly. For example if you have it your root and in root you have 'bin/release' then your path needs to be `../../HandCalculatorDll.dll` Not sure what else you can try.

Comment: The host has a file manager so I can actually browse the file system.  I put the dll into a _bin_deployableAssemblies.  As I publish I can see the dll being copied into the bin folder itself so I know it is there.  Also, using         System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/")    I can see the root folder is the wwwroot folder.  I know the correct path of the file, I just can't access it.

Comment: Mmm something just occurred to me. What trust mode is your website running in on the Web server? Shared hosting usually doesn't give you full trust mode hosting. I doubt you'll be able to run unmanaged code in medium trust mode.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue.  If you read my update above, the dll would not work when running locally on other computers which means there was a problem with the dll itself.  Though the dll does not contain any external references, I'm an idiot and I was using the debug dll not the release dll. (facepalm)